# What is the origin of the Caro-Kann Two Knights Variation?

Tags: opening, history, caro-kann

It starts with **1. e4 c6 2. Nc3 d5 3. Nf3**. I checked the 1984 edition of *The Oxford Companion to Chess*, and all it said was that it was popular in the 1950s. Any information would be valuable to me.

```
[Title "Caro-kann - Two Knights variation"]
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "5"]

1. e4 c6 2. Nc3 d5 3. Nf3
```

Comment: Not sure about the two knights variation in particular, but heres an article outlining a more general history. https://www.chess.com/article/view/the-caro-kann-a-history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear when it originated, but the normal variation started in 1886. The first recorded game I could find using it is in 1908.

Source:[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caro%E2%80%93Kann_Defence#)

Answer (score 0):

This is the first game in 1908 I found when searched in the Mega Database. After that there were games in 1922, 1923 played by Bogoljubow, Tarrasch and Capablanca

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "Lasker Emanuel tour sim"]
[Site "Netherlands"]
[Date "1908.??.??"]
[Round "?"]
[White "Lasker, Emanuel"]
[Black "Radsheer"]
[Result "1-0"]
[ECO "B11"]
[PlyCount "21"]
[EventDate "1908.??.??"]
[EventType "simul"]
[EventRounds "1"]
[EventCountry "NED"]
[SourceTitle "EXT 2001"]
[Source "ChessBase"]
[SourceDate "2000.11.22"]

1. e4 c6 2. Nc3 d5 3. Nf3 dxe4 4. Nxe4 Bf5 5. Ng3 Bg6 6. h4 h6 7. Ne5 Bh7 8.
Qh5 g6 9. Bc4 e6 10. Qe2 Bg7 11. Nxf7 1-0
```

[image]